# What is the correct way to include localisation in python packages?

Tags: python, linux, gettext, packaging, setuptools

I am writing my own python application and I am wondering what is the correct way to include localisation in source distributions. I struggled with the documentation of [setuptools](http://pythonhosted.org//setuptools/); localisation is not even mentioned there. I use [pypabel](http://babel.pocoo.org/) to extract my message catalogues and to compile them.

**Questions**

- Is there a possibility to compile `*.po` to `*.mo` automatically before creating a source package with setup.py? Currently I have to compile everything before manually for each language...
- Where should I include those `*.mo`-files? Several linux distributions have different places for those files. In my opinion I line like this in `setup.py`

  ```
  data_files=[('share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES', ['locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/project.mo'])
  ```

  does not really make sense. It may work on a particular linux machine when installing with pip. But it may break on bsd or windows...

Answer (score 1):

For the first: there are tools for handling po-files in Python, suggest you look into [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/), then you get the [extra commands for setup.py](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/setup.html).

It should be possible to also hook the `compile_catalogs` as requisite for source build, but I haven't found need for it, as you can't test the messages from a package linked with `python setup.py develop` if you don't compile first. Also, maybe your source build does not need the `.mo` at all if you require Babel.

For the second: Our apps use the pyramid web framework, the convention there is to use package_data:

```
setup(
    # ...
    package_data={'yourpackage': ['i18n/*/LC_MESSAGES/*.mo' ]},
    # ...
```

then if your localizations are in `yourpackage/i18n/` you can use `pkg_resources` to find the path, for example:

```
pkg_resources.resource_filename('yourpackage', 'i18n')
```

will point to the location of translations.